# "[float(n)-50 for n in range(100)]" - what does this do?

Tags: python

I stumbled upon this one-liner:

```
[float(n)-50 for n in range(100)]
```

Could somebody tell me what it does? It's supposed to return a float value for a vector.

Best,
Marius

Comment: If you store that in a list variable then print, you can see the pattern easily enough.

Comment: You ran it a few times? What did it look like it did? Then you replaced some parts with simpler equivalents and ...? There is not much reason *not* to try this with the good REPL's available; no compiling or anything. (Also, perusing through the well-written Python language documentations will learn you lots.)

Comment: Maybe you should tell the author that this is equivalent to `map(float, range(-50, 50))`, which is a lot more readable.

Comment: @NiklasB. If I felt like it. That's for an answer; this was a comment. I am merely trying to encourage playing around in an environment that is well suited to it. This is a really poor question because it is "what does this [mumble of stuff] do" and not "what does X do". Problems need to be broken up into pieces and that's a skill learned by *doing*.

Comment: @pst: I think you got my comment wrong: I wasn't referring to your comment. I was suggesting this to the OP, who doesn't seem to be the author of that code :) I fully support your suggestion to just try it out and play with it in the REPL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) that reads "create a list of 100 elements such that for each element at index `n`, set that element equal to n-50".

Comment: more like: Create list of elements as float(n)-50 where n goes from 0 up to 100

Comment: I like "my" interpretaion, becuase it reads from left to right of what code sais

Answer (score 2):

It's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.
>
> For example, assume we want to create a list of squares, like:
>
> ```
> >>> squares = []
> >>> for x in range(10):
> ...     squares.append(x**2)
> ...
> >>> squares 
> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
> ```
>
> We can obtain the same result with:
>
> ```
> squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
> ```
>
> This is also equivalent to `squares = map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))`,
>   but it’s more concise and readable.

Answer (score 2):

It means the same as:

```
[float(x) for x in range(-50, 50)]
```

Or (at least in Python 2):

```
map(float, range(-50, 50))
```

which are self-explanatory if you know how list comprehensions or the `map` function work: They transform the integer range `-50...50` into a list of floats (the upper 50 is exclusive). The result is the list:

```
[-50.0, -49.0 ... 49.0]
```